# Speeding a numpy correlation program using the fact that lists are sorted

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently using python and numpy for calculations of correlations between 2 lists:  `data_0` and `data_1`. Each list contains respecively sorted times `t0` and `t1`.
I want to calculate all the events where `0 < t1 - t0 < t_max`.

```
 for time_0 in np.nditer(data_0):
        delta_time = np.subtract(data_1, np.full(data_1.size, time_0))
        delta_time = delta_time[delta_time >= 0]
        delta_time = delta_time[delta_time < time_max]
```

Doing so, as the list are sorted, I am selecting a subarray of `data_1` of the form `data_1[index_min: index_max]`.
So I need in fact to find two indexes to get what I want.

And what's interesting is that when I go to the next `time_0`, as `data_0` is also sorted, I just need to find the new `index_min` / `index_max` such as `new_index_min >= index_min` / `new_index_max >= index_max`.
Meaning that I don't need to scann again all the `data_1`.
(data list from scratch).

I have implemented such a solution not using the numpy methods (just with `while` loop) and it gives me the same results as before but not as fast than before (15 times longer!).
I think as normally it requires less calculation, there should be a way to make it faster using numpy methods but I don't know how to do it.
Does anyone have an idea?

I am not sure if I am super clear so if you have any questions, do not hestitate.

Thank you in advance,

Paul

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It will be useful to provide a sample of the data in your question. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized approach using `argsort`. It uses a strategy similar to your avoid-full-scan idea:

```
import numpy as np

def find_gt(ref, data, incl=True):
    out = np.empty(len(ref) + len(data) + 1, int)
    total = (data, ref) if incl else (ref, data)
    out[1:] = np.argsort(np.concatenate(total), kind='mergesort')
    out[0] = -1
    split = (out < len(data)) if incl else (out >= len(ref))
    if incl:
        out[~split] -= len(data)
        split[0] = False
    return np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(split, -1, out))[split] + 1

def find_intervals(ref, data, span, incl=(True, True)):
    index_min = find_gt(ref, data, incl[0])
    index_max = len(ref) - find_gt(-ref[::-1], -span-data[::-1], incl[1])[::-1]
    return index_min, index_max

ref = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,20000,(10000,)))
data = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,20000,(10000,)))
span = 2

idmn, idmx = find_intervals(ref, data, span, (True, True))

print('checking')
for d,mn,mx in zip(data, idmn, idmx):
    assert mn == len(ref) or ref[mn] >= d
    assert mn == 0 or ref[mn-1] < d
    assert mx == len(ref) or ref[mx] > d+span
    assert mx == 0 or ref[mx-1] <= d+span
print('ok')
```

It works by

- indirectly sorting both sets together
- finding for each time in one set the preceding time in the other
  this is done using `maximum.reduce`
- the preceding steps are applied twice, the second time the times in 
  one set are shifted by span